# Put a Form in the Site's Homepage

Tags: 7, forms, routes, hooks

I have the item menu in my hook_menu.

```
//Calls a function that enables creating, updating and deleting ID Templates.
$items['user/%user/myid_templates'] = array(
    'title' => 'MyID Templates',
    'description' => 'Configuration for ID Templates',
    'page callback' => 'myid_templates',   
    'page arguments' => array(1),   
    'access arguments' => array('manage_templates'),
    'file' => 'includes/myid_templates.inc',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -18,
);
```

It's working fine:

[image]

I want it to appear in the home page of my site. What shall I edit my code above? I tried the code below with no luck.

```
//Calls a function that enables creating, updating and deleting ID Templates.
$items[''] = array(
    'title' => 'MyID Templates',
    'description' => 'Configuration for ID Templates',
    'page callback' => 'myid_templates',            
    'access arguments' => array('manage_templates'),
    'file' => 'includes/myid_templates.inc',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -18,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
  $items['node'] = array(
    'title' => 'MyID Templates',
    'description' => 'Configuration for ID Templates',
    'page callback' => 'myid_templates',            
    'access arguments' => array('manage_templates'),
    'file' => 'includes/myid_templates.inc',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -18,
);
```

Comment: `$items['node']` is already used by the Node module, so another module cannot use it again. Also, the front page is not necessary that.

Comment: not working. :(

Comment: @kiamlaluno --> so is it possible to place it in the front/home page?

Comment: @kiamlaluno is correct that you can't use that path in hook_menu but you should be able to override with hook_menu_alter.   

First thing you need to do is determine what your frontpage is, you can check this by going to /admin/config/system/site-information and checking the value in default front page.    

Next you need to use hook_menu_alter to override the node modules callbacks with your own as per your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Create a block for that form and place it on your home page. I haven't actually tried it with argument but something like that should work, give it a try.

```
$items['homepage/%'] = array(
  'title' => t('My form'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('hook_myform_form',1),
  'access callback' => 'myform_custom_access_callback',
  'access arguments' => array(1),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

function hook_myform_form ($form, &$form_state,$user_id) {

}

function hook_BLOCK_myform_CONTENT() {
  return drupal_get_form('hook_myform_form');
}

function hook_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['custom_myform_for_homepage'] = array(
    'info' => t('Details'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function hook_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch($delta) {
    case 'custom_myform_for_homepage':
      $block['subject'] = t("Details"); 
      $block['content'] = hook_BLOCK_myform_CONTENT();
      break; 
  }
  return $block;
}
```